# Meaning of the kanji 圀 in 光圀

Tags: meaning, kanji, names

This a name of a traveler name from Tokaido board game. I figure out that 光 literally means, light or shine but I can't found what means or how 圀 it's translate literally to English.

Comment: Have you checked [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%9C%80)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is easily answerable with a search engine but no prior research was done.

Comment: Moreover 光圀｛みつくに｝is a proper name. Does it make sense to translate names? Anyway, If you see 光+圀（国）what do you think about?

Comment: Agreed, voting to close for lack of research.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an old or alternate form of 國 or 国( country).

Virtually, only used in 徳川(水戸)光圀 he is popular as 水戸黄門 in Japan.